# Load Maya shelves from a non-standard location without editing Maya.env

Tags: python-2.7, maya, mel

I want to load a set of custom shelves from a non-standard location without changing the `Maya.env` file. Is this possible? Ideally the solution would be in Python but mel is fine too.

Answer (score 0):

In the `script` directory in your local `maya` profile or `startup` directory in `{MAYA_INSTALL_DIR}\scripts` add a file `my_custom_script.mel` which contains:

`source "/path/to/custom/shelves/script/in/non/standard/location.mel";`